# File Browser with PySide2: get the path of the file and then kill the GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyside2

I have the following code and want to do the following:

- Most important point: Once I clicked on the file and get its filepath, I want the GUI to quit because I would then just feed that path to another script (`another_script`) which I would then import

My problems is that, after the script successfully prints the path of the selected file, the GUI does not kill itself and i cannot run `another_script` and I'm stuck in the terminal

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.openFileNameDialog()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
            "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", 
            "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", 
            options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
import another_script
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have selected the file the event loop will still continue to run, a possible solution is to call QXApplication.quit() with a QTimer but there is still a problem: that method will make the exec_() method return 0 which is taken by sys.exit() and consequently the application will be closed. But all of the above is unnecessary since if you just want to get the path of a file then you don't need to use a QWidget, you can use the following:

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog


def get_filename():
    app = QApplication([])
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        None,
        "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()",
        "",
        "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)",
        options=options,
    )
    return fileName


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = get_filename()
    if filename:
        print(filename)
```